# PowerShell SharePoint Web.RecycleBin.Delete - "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Good day,

I am using the Web.ProcessBatchData to delete items from a SharePoint list en masse. These items go into the Web Recycle Bin and I would like to delete those items. I have discovered that Web.RecycleBin.DeleteAll() seems to work fine. However, when I pass a list of GUIDs to the Web.RecycleBin.Delete(Guid []) method I get "Value does not fall within the expected range." I put a breakpoint in the code and it seems to be giving me a collection with the correct counts and (with no real easy way to verify them) GUIDs so I am missing something here.

Thanks in advance.

```
$deletions = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Guid]
foreach ($i in $list.Items)
{
    $deletions.Add($i.UniqueId);
    $str.Append([System.String]::Format($command, $i.ID.ToString()));

}
$web.RecycleBin.Delete($deletions.ToArray()); #Error here, DeleteAll() works fine.
```